# Is there a way to stop a Command Button cell from highlighting in KendoUI grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So I have a standard KendoUI Grid.  Works great.  I have highlighting set to "Row".  Works great.

At the end of each row is a cell with two command buttons (Edit and Delete), and I would like to NOT have that cell highlighted when selected.

Anyone have ideas?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the style for just the cell containing buttons is a little tricky since you need to *reenable* the default styles and that depends on KendoUI style and then you need to apply to the cell.

One way of doing it to the cell containing the buttons is defining this cell as:

```
{ command: ["edit", "destroy" ], attributes: { "class": "ob-style" } },
```

Where I add an attribute to the row that is `class: "ob-style"`.

For re-applying the styles, you should check the styles and then apply it to both row and alternative row. Something like:

```
.k-alt .ob-style {
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245)
}

.ob-style {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not what I'm looking for.  What I am trying to do is keep the cell from being highlighted when I click on any part of the row in the grid.  Kendo grid (if set to do so) will highlight the entire selected row.  I don't want the last cell (with the command buttons in it) to be highlighted.

And actually there are lots of ways to remove CSS class or setting data from a DOM element using JQuery or similar scripting.  But that's not going to help here.  Thanks though.

Comment: Do you mean that what you want is that when you select a grid row, all cells but the ones having commands being styled as `k-selected`?

Comment: About the second part (_there are lots of ways..._) sorry but you misunderstood what I meant as not possible. I know that you can remove `class` from a definition usine jQuery _but_ what I mean is that while leaving the class, you cannot remove what that class is defining and you need to overwrite it OR remove the class if it does not have side effects. But I agree, this is not going to help here.

Comment: Ah.. yes.  Ok, I understand what you mean.  Thanks for that.  And yes.. I need to not have the cell with the buttons adopt that class... or I guess what I need would be to overwrite it back to no background and highlight.  Hmm...

Comment: Wonderful.. thanks OnaBai.  I don't have time to test at the moment, but I am going to test as soon as I'm back in the office.  Thanks again.